# Is it worth separating "style" from "layout" in CSS

Tags: css

One of my biggest trouble with CSS has always been how tricky it is to position stuff appropriately.

Now matter how hard I try to understand things, I always need a couple of tries before I can guess which must be floatted in which direction related to what.

Now, my trouble is, I usually at some point have code like this :

```
<div class="someContainerThatWillWorkAsALine">
  <div class="someOtherContainerThatWillWorkAsAcolumn">
    <div class="StuffInAcolumn">
      ...
    </div>
```

The only purpose of classes like this is to say :

- "child, please go from left to right"
- "except you guys, please go from top to bottom"
- "you, stop disturbing your brother and go 5px to the left, you're grounded"
- "johnny, you're the last of your breed, please clear all those floating nonsense"

I sometimes come to wonder if I'm writing software, or trying to find the right way to turn the antenna to receive old-style analog TV.

> "Ok, just a little more to the right, please... 
>   No, not quite there yet. 
>   Perfect now, don't move !"

Besides, those classes have no real semantic, so it's *very* hard to give them a meaningful name. This makes CSS pretty hard to read, and, even worse, pretty hard to *write* because I get a panic attack every time I have to choose a name for "yet-another-class-that-simply-tells-a-block-to-act-as-a-line". Because as every class name is global to your web2.0-y-one-page-site, you don't want to collide with used names.

So how do you tackle this kind of problems ? 
Do you :

- leave the "positioning" (layout?) css code inline with your html, and restrict CSS to actual styling (as in "this should be blue, this should be written in bold, etc...") ?
- simply have one "act-as-a-line" and "act-as-a-column" class (meaning your html code contains classes that only deals with layout), which kinda defeats the "keep layout out of my html" spirit ? And give a more meaningful class for other cases ?
- use a convention for the names ?

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: I think [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/) addresses many of the points you raise far more eloquently than I possibly could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand your pain, but the more you use CSS/html the easier it becomes. To the point that you end up loving it.

> Is it worth separating “style” from “layout” in CSS

Yes, absolutely! If you use a layout framework you won't have all those crazy classes. Then you can concentrate on style. Both the layout and styles will be in a CSS file.

Never inline style - maintain the useful [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

[This article](http://wardley.org/computers/web/separation.html) addresses why the separation of concerns will benefit your website long-term.

Comment: Seriously doubt I'll ever *love* it (I mean, "floating" ? really ? come oooooon ...). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8):

The approach I take is to separate my CSS rules into three different "sections":

- Layout rules (width, height, padding, margin, floating or not, positioning, etc.)
- Type rules (font size, font weight, etc.)
- Appearance rules (font colour, background colour, CSS3 with vendor prefixes, etc.)

Here's an example from a current project:

```
    .OrderActionsPane {

    /* --- Layout --- */

    height: 45px;
    padding: 3px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;

    /* --- Typography --- */

    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;

    /* --- Appearance --- */

    background: #fff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(100%, #ededed));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top center, #fff, #ededed);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top center, #fff), #ededed);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top center, #fff, #ededed);
    background: linear-gradient(top center, #fff, #ededed);

    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25);

    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #e6e6e6;

}
```

The reason I do this is that layout rules (box model stuff, mostly) has the largest effect on your layout. Type rules can also affect your layout (if you have a fluid container and increase your font size, for instance, the container may grow). Appearance styles have no effect on your layout.

Notice that I'm separating the border rules. It would be easier to write "border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6" as shorthand, but then you would lose the separation between the appearance and the layout effects of the border.

Other considerations could also be the units you are using in your layout. Px will make for a more solid layout, but if you use percentages or ems for a more mobile-friendly or scalable layout, you may need to do a bit more thinking.

My way isn't necessarily the only one or the best, and the solution may vary depending on the constraints of your platform (whether it allows you to separate rules like this into a "Layout.css" file and a "Theme.css" file, for instance, where the theme file only changes the appearance and can be swapped out for another one for a completely different look).

I think this is something that every front-end dev / CSS coding guy (or girl) bumps up against at some point! As you learn more about CSS, you'll start thinking "There MUST be a better way to do this". Eventually, if you put the effort in, you'll find a solution. :)

Have a look at SMACSS for more food for thought: http://smacss.com/book/type-layout

Comment: Something else I forgot to mention. To lessen the impact of padding and border rules on the layout, use this rule:

'box-sizing: border-box'

This will include border widths and padding into the width of the element... which makes it much easier to lay out pages and elements in my opinion!

Comment: I like this separation a lot, but unfortunately I tend to think too much about cases like `border-width`: isn't the fact that some element has a border a matter of styling (as in: the appearance)? There are other examples where I can't quite make up my mind, so I eventually tend to give up and merge it all :-/

Comment: Dito for `font-size`: doesn't this have strong effect on layouting (think line breaks etc.)? Or things like `white-space`?

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple class names - one set for positioning, one for styling. DO NOT USE INLINE STYLES.

The conventions are up to you.

Comment: Why this do-not-use-inline-styles-dogma?

Comment: Because is completely breaks the idea of separating your code from your styles!

Comment: I wouldn't say never use inline styles, as there are times when they're useful, but generally no.

Comment: When do you find it useful to inline styles?

Comment: But if your code has lots of class="be-a-line class1 class2" , are your *really* still separating your code from your style ? Or is it simply that "layout" is not really style, hence this handling in ahem, a "stylesheet" language ?

Comment: You can argue semantics, but using multiple classes is how it works in  the real-world and that's really all that matters, given the current technology.

Comment: @Diodeus - Go by the most basic rule of inline CSS vs. a stylesheet: if you're going use a style more than once, it's worth adding it to a stylesheet. I see what you're saying about how adding many classes isn't necessarily more efficient/semantically reasonable than inline, but if abstracted out in a thoughtful way it can be efficient and understandable.

Comment: Oops - meant to address the above comment to @phtrivier